# Adjusting Tableau Date Values to per month

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm looking to adjust the basic Tableau time frame from the ISO/Gregorian format to a customized one.  Currently, I'm displaying data in a line chart by Month and week.  The week format is based on 52 weeks ie 'Week 43' = 10/17-10/23.  I would like to display the week time line relative to its given month ie the column would read October 'Week 1' = 10/01 - 10/07, 'Week 2' = 10/08-10/14 and the following month would reset the weeks to start at zero.  Is this achieved by a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few features in Tableau that will help you with this.

Read through the on-line help about creating custom dates, setting fiscal years for date fields. The custom date feature is based on the Tableau function DATE_TRUNC() so you might want to read about that as well.

The short answer though is - right click on your date field in the data pane on the left margin, then set the fiscal year start under the default properties and create a custom date at the week level. You want to create a date value, not a date part.

Then use your custom date to build your viz, and change it between discrete and continuous depending on how you want to present your values.